# SQL Error (137): Must declare the scalar variable "@sql"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019, heidisql

I was unable to run the following SQL commands. First I thought that it might be because "max" is not defined but on the internet there SQL scripts with "max". I cannot understand what is wrong with the script. May be version of the SQL Server is wrong. I get an error:

> SQL Error (137): Must declare the scalar variable "@sql"

Code:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) = ''

SELECT @sql += 'ALTER TABLE ' + Quotename(tbl.name) + '  DROP CONSTRAINT ' + Quotename(cons.name) + ';'
 FROM SYS.DEFAULT_CONSTRAINTS cons
 JOIN SYS.COLUMNS col ON col.default_object_id = cons.object_id
 JOIN SYS.TABLES tbl ON tbl.object_id = col.object_id
 WHERE col.[name] IN ('id_card_number');

--PRINT @sql
EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

[image: MSSQL query]

[image: HeidiSQL]

Comment: Are you 100% that is the error you are getting? If you run this ENTIRE block all at once, there is no way you can get that message. However, if you run the lines individually, that could be your problem.

Comment: Do you have any `GO` statements sprinkled around? At the very least, add a `;` terminator after your `DECLARE` statement.

Comment: FYI, using the syntax `SELECT @Variable += ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](//docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your data in a row by row order, which there is *no* guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. You are using SQL Server 2019, so why are you not using `STRING_AGG`?

Comment: How are you running this? Is the application using semi colon as a batch delimiter? (DBeaver does this I believe)

Comment: @DavidG, I have tried both by normally running and running the selection by selecting everything.

Comment: @Dai, there are no `GO` statements.

Comment: feel free to attach a screenshot where one can see the code and the error (as well as application)

Comment: That isn't SSMS nor ADS; what are you using? Do you have semicolon (`;`) set to the batch separator? If so, I suggest changing that to `GO`, or using a client that doesn't have such a bug.

Comment: @ThomA, should it be SSMS? Can't I run it from HeidiSQL? I think I don't have batch separator.

Comment: I'm not familiar with HeidiSQL, but I would suggest that the problem is your settings and that, like mentioned above in a couple of comments, you have `;` as your batch terminator, not `GO`, so which means that when you get to `SELECT @sql += ... FROM` (which again, you should *not* be doing), the second statement this in a new batch and so the variable no longer exists. I suggest having a look at the application's settings and configuring them appropriately.

Comment: It looks like HeidiSql ahas a choice between "Send queries one by one" or "Send batch in one go", and the latter must be used to achieve compatibility with what is considered normal SSMS / SQL Server behaviour. See my answer below for some more details.

Comment: In this specific case simply removing the semi colon at `WHERE col.[name] IN ('id_card_number');` should work - as it isn't in a place where this would be required - and looks like this is the only place where you have a semi colon between the declaration of the variable and the final usage of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using HeidiSQL, which has a choice between **Send queries one by one** or **Send batch in one go**.

The latter must be used to achieve compatibility with what is considered normal SSMS / SQL Server behaviour.

See answer in https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=38756#p38764

Screenshot:
[image]